# Chess Board Coloring of a Paper using an Arbitrary Curve

Tags: graph-theory, plane-curves, coloring

Pick a piece of paper and a pen. Put the pen on a starting point and begin to draw an arbitrary curve and don't withdraw your hand until you reached the starting point. You can meet your curve during drawing in some *one point* intersections but not more (like a line intersection). For example the left curve is allowed but the right one is not.

[image]

Now your paper is divided to some areas. We call two areas "neighbors" if their *common borderline* has more than one point. A "coloring" for the areas of the paper is such that two neighbor areas have different colors. Recall the chess board coloring.

> **Question:** Is it true that there is a $2$-coloring (Black and White) for the areas of a paper when we draw an arbitrary curve on it as described above? If yes, why?

**An Example:** Note to the coloring in the following shape. You can try on more complicated shapes by your own. It seems to be always true that we can do this by $2$ colors.

[image]

Comment: Vihart mentions this in this www.youtube.com/watch?v=heKK95DAKms video at 3:00. She also hints that the whole thing has to do with 2-colorability of graphs of even degree.

Comment: Comment of user132181 along with the answer given by @Rahul solves the problem. I shall wait for Rahul to expand his answer and if he doesn't do it, i shall give a more detailed answer.

Comment: I have an intuitive answer: start drawing with W (white) on right side of your pen and B (black) on left side. Whenever your cross a line, colour newborn inner faces based on the side of the pen they appear (left/right), and *flip* the colours on the left and right sides of the pen. (Some details need to be worked out: i think we need to do something special at 1st crossing and when we end at starting point). This seems to be basically same idea as Rahul's Answer.

Comment: @CyriacAntony: Please go ahead.

Comment: @Rahul Sorry I didn't get a proof. Also I am convinced that the proof of correctness of the method (if it is correct) has nothing to do with winding numbers. So please feel free to expand on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Probably. We can create a graph $G$ from the drawing by assigning each region to be colored a vertex. Then if $u$ and $v$ are vertices of $G$, $(u,v)$ is an edge if and only if the regions represented by $u$ and $v$ share a face.

This should result in a bipartite graph which is always two colorable, which in turn implies your picture is two colorable.

The only thing you will have to prove is that $G$ is bipartite. But that shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: What part of this proof doesn't work for a curve on an arbitrary surface (like the Mobius band, for which the claim is not true)? At the very least, you're using the Jordan Curve Theorem in some way here.

Comment: I am not certain, but if this isn't true on a Möbius band, then I would say that my graph cannot be embedded on the band and retain its bipartite nature. I am not that familiar with topological graph to say much more than that.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I think the problem isn't with the embedding as much as it is with the vertices themselves. A vertex is selected so that it represents a face of our closed curve, but there are curves on the Mobius strip for which no face can be determined. Thus there can be no corresponding vertex. This means that I could have an empty graph. That is one with no vertices or edges.

Comment: Right: that a simple closed curve always bounds a region is definitely true in the plane, but fails to be true in other  surfaces. But if you take a Mobius strip and divide it into tiny region (e.g. make the strip from graph paper, and use the graph-squares as "regions") then your construction works fine...but the bipartiteness fails. That makes me think that the proof that G is bipartite depends, at the very least, on orientability of the plane, so you "shouldn't be too difficult" might be overoptimistic. (I suspect it's not too difficult if you don't mind the proof hiding things.:) )

Comment: Well assuming the curve is orientable, then the proof that the resulting graph is bipartite is relatively straightforward. Suppose the graph is not bipartite, then there must exist a triangle somewhere. Fix two vertices and the edge between them and observe that this represents two regions that share an edge. Now the third vertex represents another region that shares an edge with each of the original two regions. This implies that the curve follows itself somewhere along the borders between the three regions, which is impossible.

Comment: I'm not certain what it means for a curve to be orientable, since every curve's the image of a circle, which is orientable. Perhaps you mean that it's normal bundle is orientable? Even so, your statement's not quite correct: you can draw a curve on a torus that creates 5 regions, with regions $A$ and $B$ touching, and region $C$ touching both. Thus the final sentence of your previous comment depends in some critical way on the topology of the plane, not just its orientability.

Comment: A closed curve that intersects with itself at finitely many points is a planar Eulerian graph. An Eulerian graph is planar if and only if it's dual is bipartite. A graph is bipartite if and only if it is 2-colorable. So this settles the planer case. I'm not sure how to extend this idea to higher genus surfaces.

Comment: Good summary. The secret sauce is that second sentence, which uses the topology of the plane in a big way. (Indeed, the existence of a meaningful "dual" depends on orientability, as the three-node, three-edge centerline of a Mobius band shows, even before you get to the other stuff.) For higher-genus surfaces, I think that the Alexander Duality approach is probably as smooth as you're going to get.

Answer (score 1):

Colour a point black if the [winding number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number) of the curve around the point is odd.

Comment: This is the most reasonable attempt at the problem (in my opinion). Please expand on your answer and point out why the dual graph should be bipartite. Giving an intuitive explanation for winding number in the answer should be helpful.

Comment: Since I haven't mentioned the dual graph in my answer, I don't know why you expect me to explain why it should be bipartite. Anyway, the point is that the winding number changes by 1 every time you cross the curve (see "Alexander numbering" in the Wikipedia article).

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I thought by saying 'point', you meant 'a vertex in the dual graph'. Also, for the record, I thought I could give an algorithmic proof for the same with winding numbers behind the curtain; I failed. But more importantly, I am convinced that if the algorithm(in my answer) works, then it doesn't rely on winding number.

Answer (score 0):

If the curve is smooth enough, and there are finitely many self-intersections, the answer is yes. For this answer, I'm going to limit myself to a particular class of curves, though: those where at most *two* bits of curve intersect at any crossing, so you can have something that locally looks like $\times$, but not something that looks locally like an asterisk (*).

Why the smoothness and finiteness requirements?

If you think of, say, the graph of $x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x}$, between $-1$ and $1$, together with the segment of the $x$-axis between $-1$ and $1$, and connect the two ends with vertical segments, you get something with infinitely many regions, and it gets tough to say whether it's really chess-board-like.

For the case I mentioned, here's a "proof": pick a direction $v$ with the properties that

1. the tangent to your curve is in direction $v$ only finitely often, and
2. at these tangencies, the curve lies on one side of $v$ or the other (i.e., no "inflections" at points where the tangent is $v$).
3. Furthermore, at each crossing, neither tangent vector should be $v$.
4. All lines in direction $v$ intersect the curve in at most finitely many points.
5. Finally, the ray between any two crossing points or any two tangents should not be parallel to $v$.

I'm using smoothness in a big way here. [The existence of $v$ is guaranteed by Sard's Theorem, which is not an easy theorem at all, and I'm not going to prove it here.]

Rotate things so that $v$ is the positive $x$ direction.

From each point in your curve-complement, draw a ray in the positive-$x$ direction.  Count the number of intersections of this ray with your curve. If it's odd, color the square black; otherwise color it white. Don't count "tangent" intersections, or crossings. 
That gives a coloring scheme; the only remaining question is "is it checkerboard-like?".

A "sweep-line" argument takes care of this: consider the coloring of two very nearby points in a region. Are they the same? Compare their ray-curve intersections: if the points are close enough, the ray-curve intersections are pairwise close to each other, and you're good...except in two cases:

1. One ray is tangent to the curve and the other is not. Then the intersection count for the second ray is either two greater than for the first, or equal to it, as the second ray either intersection the curve near the tangency twice or not at all (by the requirement that the curve lie entirely on one side of its tangent line, i.e, condition 2). (I'm using condition 5 to ensure that the ray is tangent to the curve at only ONE point so that this analysis makes sense)
2. The two rays have a crossing between them. This doesn't actually cause a problem, as the intersection of ray1 with the crossing parts can be paired up with the intersections of ray2 with the crossing parts.  (The details for this part use property 3 and property 5)

So evidently a connected region has locally-constant color, hence constant color.

Clearly if two regions share a boundary (they're "neighboring countries") then their intersection-counts will differ in parity: A right-pointing ray from a point near the boundary between the left country and the right country will pass through that boundary; for a point just on the other side of that boundary (such a point exists by condition 4), the right-pointing ray will lack that intersection.

In short: even stating the claim really clearly isn't all that easy, and the proof isn't trivial either. It's somewhat simpler if you're willing to say that your curve is a (possibly self-intersecting) polygon with finitely many vertices (i.e., a "connect the dots drawing"); in that case, the conditions I wrote above are all easy to verify.

I believe that there's a one-liner proof using Alexander duality and mod-2 homology/cohomology, but that's not very illuminating, and there's a ton of machinery behind it.

Answer (score 0):

I shall try to give an intuitive colouring method that doesn't require much mathematical background.
I though I clearly understood why this method of colouring works; but now I doubt it. 
Anyway I shall try to give a colouring method for any such drawing using only 2 colours without presenting proof for validity (I don't have one now). Any proof for validity, or counterexample that this wouldn't work is welcome.

I shall try to explain the colouring method with figures. Let us use colours 1 and 2 instead of black and white.

We first give colour 2 to the plane. We place the pen at a point $p$ on the plane. Without lose of generality, we may assume that will draw a crossing at point $p$. We keep colour 1 on the right side of the pen and colour 2 on the left side. When we reach a crossing point, we recolour the two 'newborn' faces with depending on which side of the pen they appear at the point of crossing (see the figure). At each crossing, we interchange the colours on the left and right sides of the pen. This continues till we finally reach the starting point.

[image]

Comment: I shall give a proof if I get one!

Comment: Sorry to post a question instead of an answer.